# Prevent Modal from closing on click submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have bootstrap modal and always close when i click "Reject".
Why is the preventDefault() not stopping the button from submitting when notes field is empty?

modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_reject" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="form-group has-error">
              <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Add Note <b style="color:red;">*</b></label>
              
              <div style="margin-left: 5%;margin-right: 5%;">
              
              <textarea id="NOTES_REJECT_SV" name="NOTES" class="form-control" required  style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
              
              </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="modal-footer ">
 

        <button type="button" id="submit" form="form" style="width:150px;height:40px;text-align:center;" class="btn  btn-ok  pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light pull-right" style="width:120px;height:40px;" data-dismiss="modal" >CANCEL</button>
          </div>
           </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my Javascript :

```
$('#modal_reject').on('click','#submit',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    var NOTES = document.getElementById("NOTES_REJECT_SV").value;
    
  
    if(NOTES == ''){
     
      $('#modal_reject').modal('hide')
     
      
      return false;
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply **[.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)** `jQuery` to get the value of your notes. I would not rec-emend mixing up the `jQuery` and `JS` together to avoid confusion.

The reason your modal was still hiding that you have `data-dismiss="modal"` in your modal `reject` button.

I have simplified your code and is working. If you do not put anything in notes area it will hide the modal or else it will stay and you can do the rest of stuff there.

Also using inline CSS is not a good practice. Bootstrap allow a lot of native class to used do you can want label `*` *red* you can just used text-danger class to do that instead of inline CSS.

You can read more on bootstrap Modal and other [details here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/)

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
$('#modal_reject').on('click', '#submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //get notes
  var notes = $('#notes_reject_scv').val();

  //if notes are empty hide the modal
  if (!notes) {
    $('#modal_reject').modal('hide')
    console.log('Notes were empty! Modal disappeared')
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_reject">
  Open Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_reject" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group has-error">
        <label class="control-label"> Add Note <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <textarea id="notes_reject_scv" name="NOTES" class="form-control" required style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VianIrfandy Thanks heaps. I provided a working answer and full details as well for you.

Comment: how i do the opposite?, like when note is empty . modal didnt close..

Comment: @VianIrfandy You can remove the `if ` condition - if you do not want the modal to close even if notes are empty.

Comment: if notes are empty modal didnt close, but if notes not empty modal close..

Comment: @VianIrfandy Just remove `!` from the if condition. Thats mean if there is a value in notes it will close else not. if `(notes) {
    $('#modal_reject').modal('hide')
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the click envent on tre #submit button as described below

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var NOTES = document.getElementById("NOTES_REJECT_SV").value;
  ...
});
```